# Cluster hh:mm in 3 minute intervals in dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, time, group-by

I have a dataframe containing tweets during a 1.5 hour time span (from 21:23 to 22:48). One of the columns in my dataframe indicates the timestamp hh:mm (this is of class character). I want to plot my data (e.g nr of tweets) over time but cluster it in 3 minute intervals (so I will get cleaner overview when creating a barplot, than clustering it by the minute). Can someone explain to me how this would work?

So the result I want to achieve is that in the example dt below is:

a, b, c, and d are clustered in group 1

e, f, g, h, and i are clustered in group 2

j, k, and l are clustered in group 3

```
dt <- data.frame(text = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"), 
                 time = c("21:23", "21:23", "21:24", "21:25", "21:26", "21:27", "21:27", "21:28", "21:28", "21:29", "21:30", "21:31"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the bins option where you can specify the number of bins, that is number of buckets. For example,

```
ggplot(<your options>) + geom_histogram(bins=30)
```

I used 30 since there are 3 *30 = 90 mins of data. But you can make it a variable.

Comment: on the y axis I want to count the number of text elements (number of tweets), trying it like this it gives me an error..